# org.w3c.dom.Document object in RFT

Tags: xpath, rft

I am trying to use xpath in RFT. Searching over the net threw this code at me-

```
private static NodeList getNodesWithXPath(Document document, String xpathStr)
    throws XPathExpressionException {
        NodeList nodes = null;
        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
        if (xpathStr != null) {
            XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xpathStr);
            Object result = expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            nodes = (NodeList) result;
        }
        return nodes;
    }
```

Now, I am new at RFT and totally at a loss about how to access the 'Document' object? Trying to typecast TestObject into this throws an exception. I could see a few examples stating something like

`Document doc = parse(xmlFileLocation)`

but I am not sure what this xmlFileLocation means. I have a simple web page where I need to identify the element using xpath.

P.S. - I understand there are other ways of identifying the object using atDescendant, etc, but I need to explicitly use xpath here due to some reasons.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They are different `Document` objects.

I think you [got the code from IBM developerworks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/configure-applications-programmatically-rational-functional-tester/index.html?lnk=uctug_ratl_dw_2013-03-20_live_dw), and that is a document obtained from an XML file, thus browsable with XPATH.

RFT *Document* is `com.rational.test.ft.object.interfaces.DocumentTestObject`
while XML related one probably is `org.w3c.dom.Document`.
Totally different classes.

[XPath is not supported by RFT](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21637920) and also [no answers in the forums](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014214629).

If you need XPath queries in your pages try something else, like [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).